# Changes not reflecting in UI after value changes Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 8.0 application. I have a span items in which value gets displayed after getting response from API on page loading . There are 3 dropdowns, which on selection triggers the api and fetched the data.

**Problem:** When the page is loaded for first time the value gets displayed but when i select soemthing from dropdown the api get called and fetched the data in the variable but it is not getting reflected in the UI.

**Below is the code for better understanding**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { GlDashboard } from "../../interfaces/glDashboard.interface";
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {WindowRefService} from '../../../gl-common/services/gl-window-ref.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'gl-plm-status-panel-dashboard',
    styleUrls: ['../gl-plm-dashboard-status-panel/gl-plm-dashboard-status-panel.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './gl-plm-status-panel-dashboard.component.html'

})
export class GlPlmStatusPanelDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    isShowNote: boolean

    @Input('dashboard') dashboard: GlDashboard;
    @Input('isShowForecast') isShowForecast;
    @Input('status') status;
    @Input() subPanel = false;
    @Input() title = '';
    customerHealthIndexAvg: any;
    customerHealthIndexLatest: any;
    customerResponseRate: any;
    checkURL:any;
    isOpenSubPanel = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,private winRef: WindowRefService) {}
    toggleSubPanel(): void {
      this.isOpenSubPanel = !this.isOpenSubPanel;
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
      debugger;
      this.getCustomerProjectValues();
    }
    /*custom code to get customer project values*/
    getCustomerProjectValues(){
      debugger;
      if(window.location.href.includes('/plm/health')){
        localStorage.setItem('rateFlag','true');
        let projID: any;
        projID = localStorage.getItem('projectId');
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('projectStartTime'),localStorage.getItem('projectEndTime'));
        this.http.get(this.winRef.nativeWindow.glAppsApiUrl+`/plm/api/v1/project/${projID}/customer/index?start_time=${localStorage.getItem('projectStartTime')}&end_time=${localStorage.getItem('projectEndTime')}`).subscribe((response:any)=>{
          debugger;
          console.log(response);
          this.customerHealthIndexAvg = response.customer_index;
          this.customerHealthIndexLatest = response.customer_latest_index;
          this.customerResponseRate = response.response_rate;
          console.log(this.customerHealthIndexAvg,this.customerHealthIndexLatest,this.customerResponseRate);
        },(error:any)=>{
          console.error(error);
        })
        this.checkURL = true;
        this.subPanel = true;
      }
      else{
        this.checkURL = false;
      }
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="gl-plm-status-panel row">
    <div class="col-lg-30  col-md-32 col-sm-30 col-30 gl-status-panel-separator">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-20 col-md-25 col-sm-60 ">
                <div class="score-cont"
                     ngbTooltip="Shows the average success state of projects within the selected period. (For incomplete periods includes forecast till the end of selected period.)"
                      placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.average_health|glDashboardStatusColor:'health'">{{dashboard.average_health|glPlmNAPipe : '%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number">Health index</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-label d-none d-xl-block">(average)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-20 col-md-35 col-sm-60 ">
                <div class="score-cont"
                     ngbTooltip="This rate shows how many risks became issues within selected period"
                      placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.conversion_rate|glDashboardStatusColor:'convers'">{{dashboard.conversion_rate|glPlmNAPipe : '%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number">Risk-to-Issue Conversion</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-20 col-md-30 col-sm-60">
                <div class="score-cont last-score"
                     ngbTooltip="Response Rate shows PM's self-assessment passing rate within selected period"
                      placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.response_rate|glDashboardStatusColor:'rate'">{{dashboard.response_rate|glPlmNAPipe : '%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number gl-response-rate-label">Response Rate</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-28 offset-lg-2 col-md-26 offset-md-2 col-sm-30 col-30 gl-panel-label-cont">
        <div class="row plm-status-panel-title-wrap">
            <div class="plm-status-panel-title-wrap__title">{{title}}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-20 col-md-30 col-sm-60 "
                 ngbTooltip="Shows the latest success state of projects within the selected period that is re-calculated dynamically during a day according to newly created or closed issues."
                 placement="bottom" openDelay="1000"
            >
                <div class="score-cont">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.current_health|glDashboardStatusColor:'health'">{{dashboard.current_health|glPlmNAPipe : '%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number gl-response-rate-label">Health index</div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-label">(latest)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-20  col-md-30 col-sm-60"
                 ngbTooltip="Shows the number of active risks for the selected period."
                 placement="bottom" openDelay="1000"
            >
                <div class="score-cont">
                    <span class="score">{{dashboard.risk_count|glPlmNAPipe}}</span>
                    <span class="gl-score-label-wrap" *ngIf="dashboard.risk_count !== null && dashboard.risk_count !== undefined">
                        <span class="priority-low gl-score-label"> <i class="glicon-circle-lined"></i></span>
                        <span class="priority-medium gl-score-label"> <i class="glicon-circle-lined"></i></span>
                        <span class="priority-high gl-score-label"> <i class="glicon-circle-lined"></i></span>
                    </span>
                    <div class="label-number">Active Risks</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-20 col-md-30 col-sm-60 "
                 ngbTooltip="Shows the number of active issues for the selected period."
                 placement="bottom" openDelay="1000"
            >
                <div class="score-cont">
                    <div class="dots-div">
                    <span class="score">{{dashboard.issue_count|glPlmNAPipe}}</span>
                    <div class="gl-score-label-wrap" *ngIf="dashboard.issue_count !== null && dashboard.issue_count !== undefined">
                        <span class="gl-label-fill-round-yellow gl-score-label"><i class="glicon-circle"></i></span>
                        <span class="gl-label-fill-round-light-orange gl-score-label"><i class="glicon-circle"></i></span>
                        <span class="gl-label-fill-round-red gl-score-label"><i class="glicon-circle"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="label-number">Active Issues</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="subPanel" class="gl-plm-status-panel gl-plm-status-sub-panel" [ngClass]="{'open': isOpenSubPanel}">
    <span (click)="toggleSubPanel()" tabindex="0" class="gl-plm-status-sub-panel__icon-wrap">
        <i *ngIf="!isOpenSubPanel" class="glicon-vm glicon-arrow-double-down"></i>
        <i *ngIf="isOpenSubPanel" class="glicon-vm glicon-arrow-double-up"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="gl-plm-status-sub-panel-wrap">
        <div class="gl-plm-status-sub-panel__row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-30 col-sm-60" *ngIf="checkURL === false">
                <div class="score-cont last-score"
                     container="body"
                     ngbTooltip='This rate shows the percentage of risks in the status "Active", with the action plan against no action plan.'
                     placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.risks_with_plan|glWidgetSubPanelColor:'health'">
                        {{dashboard.risks_with_plan|glPlmNAPipe : '%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number gl-response-rate-label">Risks with action plan</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-30 col-sm-60 "
                 container="body"
                 ngbTooltip="This rate shows the number of risks with the action plan but the deadline overdue."
                 placement="bottom" openDelay="1000"
                 *ngIf="checkURL === false"
            >
                <div class="score-cont">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.outdated_risks_with_plan|glWidgetSubPanelColor">{{dashboard.outdated_risks_with_plan|glPlmNAPipe}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number gl-response-rate-label">Outdated Risks with action plan</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-25 col-sm-60 " *ngIf="checkURL === false">
                <div class="score-cont"
                     container="body"
                     ngbTooltip='This rate shows the percentage of issues in the status "Active", with the action plan against no action plan.'
                     placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.issues_with_plan|glWidgetSubPanelColor:'health'">{{dashboard.issues_with_plan|glPlmNAPipe : '%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number">Issues with action plan</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-35 col-sm-60 " *ngIf="checkURL === false">
                <div class="score-cont"
                     container="body"
                     ngbTooltip="This rate shows the number of issues with the action plan but the deadline overdue."
                     placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                          [ngClass]="dashboard.outdated_issues_with_plan|glWidgetSubPanelColor">{{dashboard.outdated_issues_with_plan|glPlmNAPipe}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number">Outdated Issues with action plan</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- custom code for showing customer satisfaction health index average -->
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-35 col-sm-60 " *ngIf="checkURL === true">
                <div class="score-cont" container="body"
                    ngbTooltip="This rate shows the average customer health index."
                    placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                        [ngClass]="dashboard.outdated_issues_with_plan|glWidgetSubPanelColor">{{customerHealthIndexAvg}}{{'%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number">Customer Health Index(avg)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- custom code for customer satisfaction response rate -->
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-35 col-sm-60 " *ngIf="checkURL === true">
                <div class="score-cont" container="body"
                    ngbTooltip="This rate shows the customer response rate."
                    placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                        [ngClass]="dashboard.outdated_issues_with_plan|glWidgetSubPanelColor">{{customerResponseRate}}{{'%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number">Customer Response Rate</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- custom code for showing customer satisfaction hleath -->
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-35 col-sm-60 " *ngIf="checkURL === true">
                <div class="score-cont" container="body"
                    ngbTooltip="This rate shows the latest customer health index."
                    placement="bottom" openDelay="1000">
                    <span class="score"
                        [ngClass]="dashboard.outdated_issues_with_plan|glWidgetSubPanelColor">{{customerHealthIndexLatest}}{{'%'}}</span>
                    <div class="label-number">Customer Health Index(latest)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: value is showing in console when month Aug is selected]

[image: Value is updated when July is selected but not reflecting in UI]

**Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.**

Thanks

Comment: Please share your html too

Comment: @Benny I have added HTML code please check

Comment: But we can't see the dropdown in the html - that triggers `getCustomerProjectValues`. Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @Benny hi, i have uploaded dropdown image although there are errors in console but i don't think it is related to the problem

Comment: What's your change detection strategy? Please share the full html and the full class code

Comment: @Benny I am not much familiar with change detection strategy so i am just using the value stored in the variable in the template using string interpolation......i have uploaded full html and ts code

Comment: Wrap your API response in `NgZone`. for example inside `subscribe()`:
`this.zone.run(()=>{
        this.customerHealthIndexAvg = response.customer_index;
          this.customerHealthIndexLatest = response.customer_latest_index;
          this.customerResponseRate = response.response_rate;

})`

Comment: hi @NajamUsSaqib i tried wrapping the api response in NgZone but it doesn't update the UI

Comment: can you share you complete code. a stackblitz MVP will be helpful.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib it's a huge enterprise application, so to upload complete code on stackblitz will be difficult as it also requires VPN connection to run. Will have to figure out some other way

Comment: update your code with ngZone implementation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255037/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-sharma-and-najam-us-saqib).